# how to dump entire data from mongodb 2.6 to mongodb 3.4 by using replica set?

Tags: mongodb

Initially I have 3 instances of mongodb 2.6 and along with some data synchronized between all the instances. Now I  am trying to  upgrade the three instances of mongo2.6 to mongo3.4, I could successfully able to upgrade the 3 instances to 3.4, by following the documentation in mongodb website. 
[upgrade mongodb replica set to 3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-replica-set/) . But as soon as I upgrade an instance to 3.4, this instance can't able to find the member to synch the data from primary [screenshot of the error - could not find a member to synch from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAmPK.png) .

Comment: If you are following the documentation, are you also upgrading between successive releases rather than directly from MongoDB 2.6 => 3.4? Mixed versions in a replica set are only supported for adjacent major releases series (eg 2.6 => 3.0, 3.0 => 3.2). If you want to upgrade with minimal downtime you need to upgrade all members to 3.0, then 3.2, and finally 3.4. If you have authentication enabled there may be extra steps along the way to upgrade your authSchema, but all should be covered in the upgrade documentation.

Comment: Thank you Stennie, I directly upgraded 2.6=>3.4, but after doing it to 3.0, then 3.2, then 3.4, I am able to  synch the data.